# Получение из div input value с обновлением value

Tags: javascript, html, css, form, input

Есть div и есть input в value которого нужно передавать то что написано в div. Если текст в div меняется, то и в value меняется тоже - без перезагрузок страниц и так далее. Плюс к тому же input имеет type hidden. Буду благодарен за подсказку !

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  Test text 2
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="value-test" id="input">
```

Comment: А как или чем меняется текст в `div` ? Там же, где Вы задаёте текст для `div`-а, там же сразу задавайте и для `input`-а.

Comment: В div передаётся значение с калькулятора (для пользователя), а потом уходит в input value для отправки формы.

Comment: вот. Та функция, которая передаёт значение в div, и должна в input передавать параллельно.

Comment: На `input` слушай событие `input` или `change`.

Answer (score 1):

В комментах выше вам уже частично ответили, где установить обновление скрытого инпута. Вариант ниже можно использовать, только если у вас нет возможности изменить коллбеки (например библиотек). Но даже библиотеку можно запатчить как вам нужно. Поэтому это только вариант для баловства.

```js
const setter = document.getElementById("set");
const binded = document.getElementById("update");
const hidden = document.getElementById("hidden");

// здесь объявляется ненужная функция слежения за текстовым полем
// это нужно, когда у нас нет возможности влезть в код инпута-сеттера
// и определить свой input listener
const observerFn = (list, observer) => {
    list.forEach(mutation => {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        const [removed] = mutation.removedNodes;
        const [added] = mutation.addedNodes;
        if (added) {
          hidden.value = added.wholeText;
        } else if (removed) {
          hidden.value = '';
        }
      }
    });
};

// Здесь начинается абсолютно ненужное слежение на текстовым полем
const observer = new MutationObserver(observerFn);
observer.observe(binded, { childList: true });

setter.addEventListener("input", ({ target }) => {
  // Здесь вместе с установкой текста в div, нужно обновлять input[type=hidden]
  // Раскомментировать строку ниже и убрать полностью бесполезный код MutationObserver
  // hidden.value = target.value;
  binded.textContent = target.value;
  
});
// Это событие нужно, если у нас в поле инпута уже было значение
setter.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("input"));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="set" value="test">
<div id="update">Placeholder</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden">
```